# I cant use all of my pwm pins only 8 of them

Tags: esp32, pwm

Hi im new to all of this and im trying to use servo motor with PWM, so my problem is this out of 16 PWM Pins only 8 of them is working 0-7, 8-15 isnt. i read online PWM is divided to 2 groups. so do I need to do somthing extra to use the 2 groups? maybe somthing i dont know about
im adding a picutre of the setup of my code

```
     #define Servo_0 13
        #define Servo_1 12
        #define Servo_2 14
        #define Servo_3 27
        #define Servo_4 26
        #define Servo_5 25
        #define Servo_6 33
        #define Servo_7 15
    #define Servo_8 2
    #define Servo_9 4
    
    
    #define PWM_Channel0 0
    #define PWM_Channel1 1
    #define PWM_Channel2 2
    #define PWM_Channel3 3
    #define PWM_Channel4 4
    #define PWM_Channel5 5
    #define PWM_Channel6 6
    #define PWM_Channel7 7
    #define PWM_Channel8 8
    #define PWM_Channel9 9
    
    #define PWM_Resolution 8
    #define PWM_Freq  50
    
    String str;
    
    
    void setup()
    {
     ledcSetup(PWM_Channel0, PWM_Freq, PWM_Resolution);
     ledcSetup(PWM_Channel1, PWM_Freq, PWM_Resolution);
     ledcSetup(PWM_Channel2, PWM_Freq, PWM_Resolution);
     
     ledcAttachPin(Servo_0, PWM_Channel0);
     ledcAttachPin(Servo_1, PWM_Channel1);
     ledcAttachPin(Servo_2, PWM_Channel2);
     ledcAttachPin(Servo_3, PWM_Channel3);
     ledcAttachPin(Servo_4, PWM_Channel4);
     ledcAttachPin(Servo_5, PWM_Channel5);
     ledcAttachPin(Servo_6, PWM_Channel6);
     ledcAttachPin(Servo_7, PWM_Channel7);
     ledcAttachPin(Servo_8, PWM_Channel8);
     ledcAttachPin(Servo_9, PWM_Channel9);
    
     }
    
    void colorRGB(byte valRed,byte valGreen,byte valBlue)
    {
     ledcWrite(PWM_Channel0, valRed);
     ledcWrite(PWM_Channel1,valGreen);
     ledcWrite(PWM_Channel2, valBlue); 
    }
    
    void head_End()
    {
      int vertical = map(100, 0, 180, 10, 35);
      int horizontal = map(84, 0, 180, 10, 35);
      ledcWrite(PWM_Channel0,vertical);
      ledcWrite(PWM_Channel1,horizontal);
    }
    void head_Move(int angle_h,int angle_v)
    {
      int h = map(angle_h, 0, 180, 10, 35);
      int v = map(angle_v, 0, 180, 10, 35);
      ledcWrite(PWM_Channel0,h);
      ledcWrite(PWM_Channel1,v);
    }
    
    
    void boxes(int angle1,int angle2)
    {
      int box1 = map(angle1, 0, 180, 10, 35);
      int box2 = map(angle2, 0, 180, 10, 35);
      ledcWrite(PWM_Channel8,box1);
      ledcWrite(PWM_Channel9,box2);
    }
    void loop()
    {  
      boxes(0,160);
      delay(1000);
      boxes(160,0);
      delay(1000);
    }
```

Comment: Hi אופק, welcome to SO. Please do not post screenshots of your code. Instead, edit your post and copy-paste the code into your question as text (and surround it with code tags \```). How do you determine which PWM works and which doesn't?

Comment: I check with a scope to see the waves, not mater what pin I’m using it’s workin in all of the first 7 servos but 8 and 9 don’t

Comment: And which ESP32 variant do you have? According to this only the vanilla ESP32 has 16 PWM channels, others have 6 or 8: https://espressif-docs.readthedocs-hosted.com/projects/arduino-esp32/en/latest/api/ledc.html